# How can I reuse the same watir object in the next controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir, headless

I am using watir with headless browser. I would need to perform three steps add location, add vehicle and fetch product from the another site , for the information which I want from a another website.
I am submitting these three details from my server and performing these all three step in one HTTP request with the help of watir and headless.

I just want to breakdown one http request in to three http request on my server. The request will be:
1)add_location: Fire a http request which will open headless browser and select the location.

2)add_vehicle: Fire a http request which will reuse headless browser in which location added and we will select the vehicle.

3)Fetch product: Fire a http request which will reuse headless browser  in which location and vehcile added, will fetch the product list.

I am not getting any way to reuse watir and headless session which is already open in the next http request at rails side.

Code Sample:

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController

  def add_location
    @headless = Headless.new
    @headless.start
    @watir = Watir::Browser.new
    @watir.goto('www.google.com')
    @watir.text_field(id: 'findstore-input')
              .wait_until(&:present?).set(params[:zip_code])
    @watir.a(id: 'findstore-button').click
    @watir.div(class: 'notifier').wait_while(&:present?)
  end

  def add_vehicle
    #need to resuse above @watir object in this action
  end
end
```

Comment: You can probably keep a global reference to Watir objects and pass them around to sessions but you'll need a real lot of memory

Comment: please do not store global references to variables in your code... Can you show the code you've tried and what error you are getting or what isn't working?

Comment: @pguardiario I can't use global reference to Watir objects because this functionality will be use by several users. So If I use global variable then all user will see same results. The result will be different as per user searching criteria.

Comment: Right, the idea is you would pass the reference to the open Watir browser with sessions. It's a bad idea IMHO.

Comment: @titusfortner Update code sample in the description.

Comment: @pguardiario please never advise on using global references, even if it's doable and has a HUGE memory impact, it requires all the API to be thread-safe or else...

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand, once you've initialized an instance variable in the class in the first method so long as you are calling the second method on the same instance of TestsController you'll have access to the browser instance. Typically one executes tests with Watir in the context of a test runner like RSpec or minitest which provides setup and teardown hooks that start the browser and the browser is passed in as a parameter to any classes that need to use it.

Comment: @Geoffroy I actually advised against it.

Answer (score 0):

The design change from 1 request to three has a big impact on your API, as even this simple part is now stateful, i.e. you need to keep the state between each of the three request.

Once you understand that, you have different possibilities.

1. Build your information request after request, and only when it is complete, use `watir` to get the information you need.

   This is basically just changing the API and you store the data in a session, cookie, database or whatever.

   It doesn't have a big impact on the changes you have to make, but does not bring any advantage.
2. Already forget this point, but you could pass around a global reference to your object in a session, but it has a HUGE memory impact and you could run into race condition.

   **NEVER do this**, ***please***
3. In case you really want to split the `watir` request into three different step (e.g. because it is too slow), you can use a background job to which you can transmit the user's data when it arrives (using dedicated databases, websocket, or whatever), then wait for your job to end (i.e. get a result), e.g. by trying to access it until it's available.

   This solution requires a lot more work, but it keeps your HTTP requests with your client lightweight and allow you to do any kind of complex task in the background, which would otherwise probably timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the hooks file, to initiate the browser in headless mode and assign to the variable to call within separate def to pass url to the browser.

For example:

in hooks, you can add it as below

@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: ['--headless']}

So you can reuse the @browser.goto('www.google.com') in one def and can use the same instance some other call as well.

def example1:
    @browser.goto('www.google.com')
end

def example2:
    @browser.goto('www.facebook.com')
end
.
.
.
etc

Hope this helps.